# I have created jQuery date picker in Asp.Net MVC 2 App .Its not showing date picker calendar?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datepicker

jQuery date picker not showing the calendar

I have included following JavaScript library file into my View...

**jquery.ui.datepicker.js**

```
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


   $(function () {
            $("#dateFrom").datepicker({ dateFormat: '<%= Formatter.GetJqueryDateFormatOnly() %>' });
            $("#dateTo").datepicker({ dateFormat: '<%= Formatter.GetJqueryDateFormatOnly() %>' });
        });
```

I should able to select date from date picker..but its showing nothing

Comment: check console for any errors and make sure script file path is correct

Comment: No errors in console.Its running perfectly.In view it's showing Date Picker Box also ,but if I click it calendar is not coming ,that's a issue

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the solution for it...

> I have created `Data Table` in the same view ,There is a `repeating column` in that data table therefore ,the `Date Picker` did not **initialize** properly.

**Then I comment that Table in view ,after that date picker works properly.**